# ¿Qué es MemoryStream en C#?

Tags: c#

He estado investigando un poco sobre esta clase y dice que todo lo guarda en memoria... ¿pero en que memoria? Yo pienso que es la memoria RAM, pero sigo leyendo y dice que se almacena en buferes temporales, etc. Me gustaría que me ayuden con esa duda teórica,

Comment: Si es en la memoria ram https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8. No se como sera la arquitectura de una memoria, pero si usa algun buffer eso es abstracto al la implementacion de la clase. Se supone que una memoria es el medio mas rapido para contener informacion, no creo que uses buffers, no al menos un buffer como el que usaria un disco rigido

Comment: Saludos Gian, me agrada que lances preguntas, por curiosidad, ¿has probado revisar la documentación oficial?

Comment: Acabo de revisar la malla curricular de Cibertec, les hace falta un curso de Arquitectura de computadoras, es necesario. Revisa este video sobre el tema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx0IHMGmkfw te dará nuevas ideas, ojo, te digo todo esto en buen plan. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @fredyfx, en primer lugar gracias por el elogio, en segundo lugar sí llegue a leer la documentación oficial de Microsoft, solo que no especificaban que memoria usaban, y en tercer lugar ¿cómo sabes que soy de cibertec jeje? Y es cierto nos falta un curso de arquitectura de computadoras, solo enseña lo más basico en ese curso.

Comment: Fácil, necesitaba comunicarme contigo para conversar sobre el tema y como no tienes ni una red social en tu perfil de SOes, decidí buscarte por la red,  encontré que estudias en Cibertec, fui a revisar la malla curricular y entendí el contexto global de la pregunta. Revisa el video, te ayudará a entender varias cosas. Por cierto, evita que el instituto interfiera con tu educación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La clase [MemoryStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8) crea un flujo de datos(stream) que usa a la memoria RAM como almacenamiento de apoyo en vez del disco duro o red. La clase `MemoryStream` encapsula la información almacenada como un arreglo (`array`) de bytes sin signo que se inicializa después de la creación del objeto `MemoryStream`, o el `array` también puede crearse vacío. La información encapsulada es accesada directamente en la memoria RAM. Los streams de Memoria (`MemoryStream`) pueden reducir la necesidad del uso de `Buffers temporales` y archivos en una aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Hola te dejo esta información espero que te sirva:

La secuencia debe realmente por eliminados incluso si hay una excepción (muy probable en archivo I/O) -  así que para escribir su **memorystream**, puedes utilizar:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) { memorystream.WriteTo(file); }
```

Y para leerlo de nuevo:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length]; file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length); ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length); }
```

Si los archivos son grandes, entonces vale la pena señalar que la operación de lectura se uso dos veces más de memoria como el tamaño total del archivo. Una solución a esto es crear **memorystream** de la matriz de bytes - el código siguiente se supone que no, a continuación, escribir a ese flujo.

```
memorystream ms = new memorystream(bytes, writable: false);
```

Saludos.